# Less: Show line numbers origin file and line numbers in rendered CSS

Tags: css, less

Is there any way in LESS to render the original LESS File + Line Number in the rendered CSS? 
Just as Middleman does with SASS... (I'm not sure if it is a SASS or a Middleman feature)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now an option in dotless to output this information as per sass does. the flag is "debug". It will be included in the next release - https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/186

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/), but the GitHub page for [FireLess](https://github.com/clearideaz/FireLess) (inspired by [FireSass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/), I guess) suggests that it would show the Less line number in Firebug, rather than the compiled CSS line number.

Comment: +1 this is nice, but i would prefer something that would hardcode the comments in the CSS file, because i dont use FireFox...

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea why the selected answer was chosen to be correct - it relates to a different build of LESS built for the .NET framework, not simply LESS itself.

Anyhow, yes, LESS does support this. It's not particularly well documented, but if you compile using the `--line-numbers=[comments|mediaquery|all]` [flag](https://github.com/less/less.js/wiki/Command-Line-Usage), it will compile your CSS with the debug info spec SASS established.

If you're using Grunt, and grunt-contrib-less, you can use the `dropLineNumbers` [option](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#dumplinenumbers) (really strange choice of name, imho). I typically set mine to `all`.